# How to Count Row that will Fall between 2 DateTimePicker from a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datetimepicker

Hello Guys so I am having a trouble here in counting rows that will fall between my selected date within my 2 DateTimePicker I might doing something wrong would you help me Identify it? I'm not quite sure if I'm doing this on the right way.

Here is my sample Code:

```
    Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim count As Integer

    For d As Integer = 0 To ServiceDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        If ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value <= startDate AndAlso endDate >= ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value Then
            count = count + 1
            MessageBox.Show(count)
        End If
    Next
```

Here is a screenshots of my DateTimePicker and DataGridView just to give you guys a Visualization of what I'm trying to do.
[image]

So my output here should be a message box that shows the number of rows that fall between my 2 DateTimePicker.

Comment: is the DGV populated manually or is there a datasource? Read the date test outloud to yourself.  You want the rows after the startdate and less than the ending date

Comment: I'm using a data source for this one Sir.  And yes that is what I'm trying to do here but Apparently I sudden realize that my condition is not that good enough to count the rows. Can you suggest another way to get the exact count?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your test is wrong:

```
ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value <= startDate
```

This is checking if the row is BEFORE the start date.  To avoid a `MessageBox` blizzard you could just show the result after the loop. You should also turn on `Option Strict`:  `ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value` returns `Object` but you are assigning it to a `DateTime` var. Rather than leaving these conversions to the compiler, you should handle them yourself.

It faster to access the data from the data source since that is where it actually is.  Controls are mainly for us to show data to the user. Example:

```
Dim dt As DateTime          ' temp var 
count = 0

For Each dr As DataRow In dtSample.Rows
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr(8))
    If dt >= startDt AndAlso dt <= stopDt Then count += 1
Next
```

The temp var is so the item value is converted once only for the evaluations. This will be at least 2+ times faster than iterating DGV rows (using 10,000 rows of data).  Extension methods will take less code but may be a little slower depending on the amount of data:

```
Dim count = dtSample.AsEnumerable.
         Where(Function(w) w.Field(Of DateTime)("ItemDate") >= startDt AndAlso
                w.Field(Of DateTime)("ItemDate") <= stopDt).
         Count()
```

You can also use the `DataTable.Select` method to get an array of rows matching the criteria.  That too is faster than working with the DGV, but it seems wasteful to do that just to count them.

Comment: Can you explain it to Sir more simpler? Sorry hehehe I'm not that Familiar in other VB.NET function but I can search them if you explain it to me more nice! ^_^ I'm just an average Joe when it comes to programming. I'd appreciate if you put on your example the variables that I used for my code for my better understanding because the sample code that you have given to me seems very confusing for me. Thanks

Comment: Read the first 2 sentences.  Your code should be `ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value >= startDate` to grab dates after the start date and before the end date.  The rest is just how to do it more efficiently.  I cant change it because I do not know what your data source variables are.  If you cant adapt it, dont use it.  Never use code you dont understand,